Youtube API v3 : order = date is not working
I'm junior developer.
I'm using youtube api v3 in mini project.
We are currently working on retrieving the three most recent video contents from a specific channel through the YouTube API, saving them in the database, and displaying them on the view.
However, since the last few days, I have been receiving responses in a mixed order(not published time desc) rather than the three most recent videos.
Request Url :
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=[specific channel]&type=video&order=date
&key=[my key]
Is there anyone experiencing a similar type of problem as me?
I changed the request url parameter sequence.
but it always returns same result (mixed result)

YouTube Data API v3 Search: list endpoint is not working properly in my opinion, use this working method instead.
